# What species is Adira represented as by the holo in S3E13?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

It kind of looks familiar but can't quite place it - we know the holo was meant to represent the federation members etc... but can anyone identify this species it chose to represent her as?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Xahean](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Xahean) - the same species as [Po](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Me_Hani_Ika_Hali_Ka_Po), who showed up in both parts of *Such Sweet Sorrow* at the end of S2 (which is probably why it looks familiar):

[image: Me Hani Ika Hali Ka Po]

Comment: I think you're close the truth. 
Culber looks like a normal Bajoran, Saru looks like a normal human, Gray looks like a normal Vulcan.
Why does Adira look like a human made up like for a party?

Comment: Because, @GBMan, that's how Star Trek does all their other species.

Comment: @FreeMan I don't get your point... :\

Comment: @GBMan basically all Star Trek species look like humans dressed up for a party. It was a somewhat tongue-in-cheek poke at the writers/costumers/etc for thinking in human-centric ways. Apparently, it failed...